# FileNotFound attempting to load v14.0.0.0 of "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, page-inspector

I have an MVC project thats been working perfectly until I updated my machine a week ago. 
I now receive a Binding Error when trying to run the project

Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' has detected a problem in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe'.

Additional information: The assembly with display name 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime' failed to load in the 'LoadFrom' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 2. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

If I continue past the error the project loads correctly.
However when I run the project as a web role in a cloud service, it will not run as it keeps popping up with the role is taking longer than expected.... message

I'm assuming this has to do with the binding problem when running as a stand alone project

Has anyone come across this before?

---

EDIT
I searched for the assembly reference in the config files, nothing came up.
Eventually I just reinstalled the new azure SDK.
The binding error message with the pageinspector still pops up on load but if I continue the project, it works fine. At the moment I will have to live with this annoying message until I find a solution

Answer (score 28):

i've observed this happening on a machine with Visual Studio 2013 installed.

it began happening, as best I can tell, after the VS2013 update 4.

(it may have occurred previously, but this is new for my environment)

I located this assembly in the GAC (two versions, one for VS2012, the other for VS2013) but these versions are strong named (obviously) with a version of "12.3.0.0" (take note the above resolution error is for a version "14" assembly.)

Here is the call stack for the first instance of this particular exception:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName fileName, string codeBase, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly locationHint, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool throwOnFileNotFound, bool forIntrospection, bool suppressSecurityChecks) + 0x23 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool throwOnFileNotFound, bool forIntrospection, bool suppressSecurityChecks) + 0x99 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef) + 0x25 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Loader.RuntimeLoader.GetRuntimeAssembly(out System.Reflection.Assembly runtime) + 0xdb bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Loader.RuntimeLoader.LoadRuntime() + 0x2a bytes    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Loader.RuntimeLoader.PreApplicationStart() + 0x27 bytes    
[Native to Managed Transition]  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Reflection.MethodInfo> methods, System.Func<System.IDisposable> setHostingEnvironmentCultures) + 0x142 bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Reflection.MethodInfo> methods) + 0x5a bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(string preStartInitListPath, out bool isRefAssemblyLoaded) + 0x67 bytes  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() + 0x9a bytes    
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager appManager, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, System.Security.Policy.PolicyLevel policyLevel, System.Exception appDomainCreationException) + 0x20a bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager appManager, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, System.Security.Policy.PolicyLevel policyLevel) + 0x16 bytes 
[Appdomain Transition]  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(string appId, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) + 0x12f3 bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(string appId, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) + 0x25 bytes    
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.GetAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(string appId, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) + 0x6c bytes  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateObjectInternal(string appId, System.Type type, System.Web.Hosting.IApplicationHost appHost, bool failIfExists, System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters) + 0x4d bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ProcessHost.StartApplication(string appId, string appPath, out object runtimeInterface) + 0x18f bytes 
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

This suggests the problem is Microsoft's (and not something I've done in, say, an assembly, application nor machine config.)

I spot-checked all of my configs (literally, all, my project's web.config as well as all .NET runtime machine configs, all versions/platforms) and I could not find a reference to this assembly anywhere.

To work around this mistake (which Microsoft needs to address) I've added an assembly binding redirect, as follows, to my web.config (NOT my machine configs):

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

This suggests Microsoft released a build of Visual Studio, or similar, which is binding against a future, unreleased version of these assemblies.

Hope this helps someone else out there!

Comment: Nice work. No need to uncheck Thrown Exceptions in the settings as per other answers

Comment: Confirming that this happened in my VS2010 project after installing VS2013 community edition + updates. Also confirming that this solution works. Good work! Thanks!

Comment: @Shaun Wilson
you are awesome, thanks for the "adding assembly binding redirect to the web.config" work around .

Comment: Inside what tag set does `dependentAssembly` belong?

Comment: the "dependentAssembly element" is child to the "runtime" and "assemblyBinding" elements - see MSDN for examples https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yt6ck0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: For those that encounter this and the version numbering isn't working for you, I did the following. Note that my "oldversion" range and my "newversion" are different than the original answer. You can find the correct version by looking in your GAC. <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-20.0.0.0" newVersion="12.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>

Answer (score 8):

If you uncheck Thrown Exceptions in the exception options it should stop prompting you.  I'm guessing it is part of its normal operation.  I've noticed the same thing.

Comment: this is not a solution/fix, this is a hackish workaround, as the exception is still being thrown if you ignore it. further, this is not part of normal operation, this is an egregious mistake on Microsoft's part in binding to a Visual Studio 'vNext' assembly which will never deploy with VS2013. They need to fix it.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of changing the framework files, try adding this to the web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" >
          <assemblies>
            <remove assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, 
               Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: @downvoter I don't mind that as long as it comes with a "why".

Comment: while i did not downvote your answer, i would note that doing this disables pageinspector support. this may be fine if you don't intend to use it. for more information on this feature see: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views/using-page-inspector-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Adding this `<remove/>` line is perfect for correcting errors that pop up in Visual Studio 2010 ASP.Net 4.0 websites after Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 is installed. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

We encountered a similar problem by deploying assemblies generated by ASP.NET from a developer machine to a production environment (referring to assemblies generated for .ascx and .aspx controls which are compiled at runtime).

We are (hackishly) copying and persisting such runtime generated assemblies from ASP.NET temporary compile folders (ie. "C:/Users/[USER]/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/") to avoid some recompiling as the service boots, in order to improve performance. However using assemblies compiled on a dev machine introduces dependencies to VisualStudio assemblies.

We fixed it by letting the production environment generate these assemblies on its own. We are copying and persisting these 'production' assemblies instead and the problem vanishes entirely.

Make sure you are not doing such awkward use of ASP.NET generated assemblies and it will probably fix it.