# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.NativeMethods.CloseHandle

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, yellow-screen-of-death

I have hit the yellow page of death. So I googled for the message:

> [SEHException (0x80004005): Een extern onderdeel heeft een uitzondering veroorzaakt.]
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.NativeMethods.CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle) +0
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Runtime.ArteryConnectionUtil.MappedFileExists(String fileName) +39
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Runtime.ArteryConnectionUtil.ReadAllLinesFrom(String fileName) +66
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Runtime.ArteryConnectionUtil.GetAllInstanceFileNames() +67
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Runtime.ArteryConnectionUtil.FindArteryConnection(String applicationPhysicalPath, ArteryConnectionData& connection) +48
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.PageInspectorHttpModule.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e) +351
>      System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +142
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +96

I have Win 8.1 x64 and ran VS as admin and used IIS to host my mvc 5 project. I have added this to my web.config to supress the exception as mentioned in some [other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521670/filenotfound-attempting-to-load-v14-0-0-0-of-microsoft-visualstudio-web-pageins) I found with google:

```
<assemblyBinding>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="12.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

The thing is that I have browserlink disabled. I have this in firefox and chrome, so it seems a crossbrowser/non-browser bug. I have this in visual studio 2013.4 and 2015 ctp6 (not sure which ctp is current atm)
IIS Express seems to work, but that is just a workaround. What if I insist to host from the IIS webserver.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I didn't have it the night before, but this morning it started. Now, I did rename my PC and install SQL Server between that time, so I'm thinking something got messed up in-between that time. Did you do anything similar?

Comment: No I did not change the hostname or change something to my sqlserver.

Comment: I'm experiencing this on the Windows 10 RC, as well as VS 2015 RC. The change in system for me was installing some new features. Although you didn't change the hostname or do anything with SQL, did you install/remove/modify any Windows features recently? Have you ever gotten the project to work in the past? And do any new projects exhibit the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the max of oldversion (currently 14.0.0.0) equal to newVersion (12.3.0.0) .